# Which client ID of Kafka Table use

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to build an Event Driven Application. 
It is a requirement that some services will only use Kafka events to store information, so I'm using Kafka tables.

I have two services that share the same Kafka table, it is a complex business logic, so I want to make sure that the same code build the table.

My question is: Can I share the same client id for different instances of the same Kafka Table?

I had build the example, and it works once. But now I'm having some problems. It is always given the exception: `The state store, topic-name, may have migrated to another instance.`

My both services are running in the same machine, without containers.

I'm configuring my Kafka Streams with:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationName);
config.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, applicationName + "-client");
config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ConfigurationResolver.get().resolve("kafka.broker"));
config.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
config.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, IgnoreTypeMismatch.class);
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, IgnoreTypeMismatch.class);
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericGsonSerde.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
config.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config)
streams.cleanUp();
streams.start();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

Comment: Can you post some code?  Perhaps something with the way, you're setting things up in your stream application. Also, `application.id` is what you should set, `client.id` is an internal identifier.

Comment: The behaviour without `client.id` and with the same `application.id` was the same. It only works with different `client.id`

Comment: Hmm. Tough, I am wondering if things are in a weird state because of `streams.cleanUp`. I never use that out of fear mostly.  There are some prerequisites of what to do before using it. I assume you did all that?

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html#step-2-reset-the-local-environments-of-your-application-instances

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different services, you should use two different `application.id`s. You cannot shard the same `KTable` across different services, but each service needs its own copy of the `KTable`. Thus, you either use the same code for both services to create the same `KTable`, of you let one service compute the `KTable`, write it into a topic, and let the other service consume this topic to get a copy of the `KTable`.

If you want to share a KTable, you need to merge both services into one service with a single `application.id`.